# turning picture into black and white using if statement to determine pixel

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def black_and_white(img: Image) -> Image:

    img_width, img_height = img.size
    pixels = img.load()  # create the pixel map

    # for every pixel
    for i in range(img_width):
        for j in range(img_height):
            r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
            if r < 255/2:
                r = 0
            else:
                r = 255
            if g < 255/2:
                g = 0
            else:
                g = 255
            if b < 255/2:
                b = 0
            else:
                b = 255
            pixels[i, j] = (r, g, b)

    return img
```

using pillow I tried to turn a color image into black and white image, using if statement to determine that if each pixel is closer to white or black and in turnm turn them into accordingly. but the result i got was a slightly highlted picture instead of a complete black and white picture, i was wondering what step did i do it wrong?

Comment: Why would you even expect this to produce a pure B&W image?  You are independently setting each of r, g, and b to either 0 or 255 - so `(255, 0, 255)` (magenta) is a possible result, along with the rest of the primary and secondary colors.  Note that looping over every individual pixel is an extremely inefficient way of doing this - you can directly perform the conversion via `img = img.convert(mode='1')`, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the colour black, all 3 colour components must be 0. For the colour white, all 3 colour components must be 255. At the moment, your code sets each colour component separately, so you could get a mixture such as (255,0,0) which will appear strongly red. Something like this should get you a black and white image.

```py
def black_and_white(img: Image) -> Image:

    img_width, img_height = img.size
    pixels = img.load()  # create the pixel map

    # for every pixel
    for i in range(img_width):
        for j in range(img_height):
            r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
            if (r+g+b) < 3*255/2:
                r = 0
                g = 0
                b = 0
            else:
                r = 255
                g = 255
                b = 255
            pixels[i, j] = (r, g, b)

    return img
```

This won't produce a very "natural" looking black and white image because the human eye perceives different colours as more intense than others, so green for example will look "whiter" than an equal amount of red. A common formula for doing this ([more details provided here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Luma_coding_in_video_systems)) is as follows:

```py
if 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b < 255/2:
    r = 0
    g = 0
    b = 0
else:
    r = 255
    g = 255
    b = 255
```

Comment: thank you so much i realized that i am just comparing plain RGB instead of the average colour of each pixel with all three combined!

Comment: Good point @usr2564301 - I've added the common colour proportions as an alternative.